# Unable to get the string from proxy object in js

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am receiving  response from apex class in this format

```json
[ { "Id" : "some record id" , "Name" : "opportunity name" , "Status" : "New"} ]
```

I am getting this response in
`.then(response => {`

- If I use `console.log(response)` then I am getting proxy object.
- I use `console.log(JSON.stringfy(response)` then I am getting stringifyed data( plain data)

when I am setting that response to a variable called

```js
@track oppList = [];

oppList = JSON.stringfy(response);
```

And when doing `console.log(oppList)` I am again getting proxy format

I need to use `oppList` in template for:each
Like

```html
<template for:each item={oppList} for:item="opp">
<p key={opp. Id} > {opp. Name}  
{opp.Status}
```

Comment: Proxy is just how Locker Service represents read-only objects. It should have no effect on your ability to get the values from the object. You don't need to serialize/stringify the object to JSON. Just use it like a normal variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the serialization that you need to remove, it looks like you are not writing your data to the class variable - which will give an undeclared property warning.

Change `oppList = JSON.stringfy(response);`

To `this.oppList = response`.

Also, there is one more potential issue - in your template you have written your object property getter syntax with a gap. I don't think this will work. You have the classic problem where you have more than one bug, so any fix to one of them *appears* not to work.

Change `<p key={opp. Id} > {opp. Name}`

To `<p key={opp.Id} > {opp.Name}`